# Why errors in my cogs won't show in console in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

Hello everyone i was making a bot using discord.py rewrite on pycharm but once there was a error on one of my cogs but the console didn't show any error and it didn't send any message so I had to search a lot about the error. I want to know why its like that.

My main code of the bot is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix")
client.load_extension("extension name")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

client.run('your token
```

Comment: Do you guys think to improve it or completely change it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't but google will sure help!

You forgot to end the string at `client.run` so here's the correct code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix")
client.load_extension("extension name")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

client.run('your token')
```

Comment: Sorry the string was proper but searching on Google will return this question itself